# Linking two hierarchies using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a hierarchy of `ISomething` objects, and now I am trying to get a separate objects to calculate parameters for the `ISomething` objects. I expect a pretty much one-to-one mapping.

```
public interface ISomething 
{
    void SetParameters(IParameters p);
}

public interface IParameterCalculator<TSomething> where TSomething : class, ISomething
{
    IParameters Calculate();
}
```

I would like to make it a bit more type safe, e.g. to make sure that the parameters calculated by a given calculator will fit only to the related something object. So I tried making parameters generic:

```
public interface IParameterCalculator<TSomething> where TSomething : class, ISomething
{
    IParameters<TSomething> Calculate();
}
```

I am not sure though how to consume this in the ISomething interface. In `C++` there are standard hacks with the templates to achieve this, are there similar techniques in `C#`? Or any other ideas how to link the `IParameterCalculator` hierarchy to `ISomething` in a type-safe way?

Comment: Could you show an example of classes that might implement these interfaces (in a non-generic way) so that we can try to generalize that specific example.  As it is, I just can't see what you're actually trying to do with these interfaces.

Comment: Is Calculate going to set the parameters?  I'm confused because I would imagine that you would need to set the parameter before calling the calculate method.  What are you really trying to accomplish?  Can you provide a real-world example?

Comment: @Servy The following question has an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599639/how-to-avoid-redundant-code-without-undesirable-double-cast-of-generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to make the `IParameters` also dependable on the `ISomething`s, and you'll also have to declare `ISomething` as taking a self-type parameter:

```
public interface ISomething<S> {
  void SetParameters(IParameters<S> p);
}

public interface IParameterCalculator<TSomething> where TSomething : class, ISomething<TSomething> {
  IParameters<TSomething> Calculate();
}
```

So `ISomething`s have to be declared passing their own type to the interface:

```
public class Something : ISomething<Something> {
  ...
}
```

Note that this does not prevent problems like an `ISomething` not declaring itself as the type parameter, and you'll also have to change `IParameters` to be generic. So you should balance the extra type parameters and their *semantic* constraints (self-type) to the benefit they will bring you.

This is called the curiously recurring template pattern in C++...

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.

I believe the following should work:

```
public interface ISomething<TSomething>
{
    void SetParameters(IParameters<TSomething> p);
}

public interface IParameterCalculator<TSomething>
where TSomething : class, ISomething<TSomething>
{
    IParameters<TSomething> Calculate();
}
```